# Any ideas for Delphi XE can randomly not load design package?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I've created a design package with component registration (component itself is in run-time) and some IDE menu items.

If I click on "Install" menu item in context menu from Project manager - package will be loadeded and works normally (always).

If I close IDE and restart it - package **may** be loaded or **may not** be loaded. Seeming randomly. But it's usually doesn't load, than load.

If I go to Component/Install packages - I see my package in the list, checkbox is checked, "Components" button shows components in my package, but package's executable itself is not even loaded in IDE! (I've verified this via Process Explorer). Reinstalling (remove package -> Ok -> Component/Install packages -> Add -> Ok) doesn't help. But uninstalling/installing from context menu of the project in Project manager - always helps.

I've added OutputDebugString into initialization section of each my module in the package. And I've found that initialization sections just doesn't run.

Run-time package is in the same folder as design-time package. Folder is in the PATH environment variable. I also tried to place packages in Delphi's Bin folder. No error messages. No strange/diagnostic OutputDebugStrings.

Any ideas?

P.S. I have this behaviour on 2 different machines. One is Win7, another is WinXP SP 2.

P.P.S. I wasn't able to reproduce this behaviour on Delphi 7. Same package, recompiled for D7 loads always.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I've found that new Delphi have feature of delayed package loading. This should optimize startup speed, when packages aren't loaded, when they are not needed.

This works fine for component packages, but spoils a fun for packages which (for example) modifies IDE menu.

You can tell IDE to always load your package by calling ForceDemandLoadState(dlDisable) from **Register** procedure.

P.S. Why do you always find answer by yourself almost immediately after posting a question? :D

Comment: Because in questioning you have to rethink the problem to communicate it to other people - in the end, you see the problem with another perspective. Sometimes this is enough.

Comment: The delayed package loading seems to be exactly my problem, BUT I use Delphi 6 on Windows 10 and I seem to not have the ForceDemandLoadState possibility. Is there something similar in D6?